# accessing helpers in ApplicationController.render in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using a Sprockets pre-processor to generate static HTML error pages for my app with this:

```
ApplicationController.renderer
  .new({
    http_host: 'myhost',
    https: Rails.env != 'development'
  })
    .render({
      inline: asset[:data],
      layout: 'layouts/error_page'
    })
```

The HTML comes in via `asset[:data]`, and a I render that with the `error_page` layout. This worked without issue in Rails 5, but since upgrading to 6 none of my custom helper methods are accessible if they're in the inline part of the render:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `my_custom_helper' for #<#<Class:0x00000000061b2758>:0x00007fe24c03bc28>
```

They do work if they're in the layout though, any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The inline files were `.html.erb`, renaming them to `.html` was enough to get it to work with Rails 6. The NameError was occurring before the pre-processor was even being invoked, I'm guessing Sprockets was trying to parse the ERB ahead of it.